# Why the backfacing is not working in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

[image]

[image]

On the shading mode works the way i want. Why is it different in cycles ?

As you can see. On cycles its only working inside, i want it to work outside.

Comment: Why is your second for the backface node transparent?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Putting the transparent node to be the first doesnt solve the problem. I still get black sides.

Comment: It's just the Material Preview mode you're in. I can replicate the issue but it's not an issue at all, i think that Material Preview cannot show transparency.
I'm sure that when you render the image it will look good.

Comment: But why it works the other way around ?

Comment: Btw, i did this before in another file. Its possible.